# Azure availability set or zone vm auto turn on

Tags: azure, azure-availability-set, azure-availability-zones

I have a VM that runs IIS and SQL server for an enterprise application used by around 100 users.

Right now I just have this VM but I would like to add some availability. It’s not critical to have zero downtime application but at least that if by some reason the server fails then I’m able to wake up a secondary instance and reroute traffic to it.

So I guess this is done by using Availabilty Sets but what I understand is that I have at least to have two VMs in the availability set and load balancer so traffic is redirected round robin to each VM. By using the above approach that means that I must have to pay for having two instances with same specs I guess.

What I would like and don’t know if this is possible is like having same above scenario where one the of the VMs is stopped so I don’t get any charge and in case of VM failure I can started maybe manually so the application works again. If this is possible how does the hard drive is available so that the other VM always have the latest data.

If it’s not possible then can I have then for the availabilty set a second VM with the lowest specs that my app can support so if the main VM fails at least critical users can still access the app (maybe performance won’t be great but app will work) and when main VM is functional again then main traffic is again redirected to main VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by having 2 vms with premium disks only and having one as a cold backup. single vm qualify for an SLA if they only use premium disks, SLA would be 99.9% afair.

with AV sets - you need to have at least 2 running vms.

Comment: Guess single VM with premium disks and use of Azure backup would be a cost effective solution instead of paying for second VM all together (because zero downtime is not a requirement here)

Comment: So with Azure backup and premium disk and only one VM is enough? So in case VM fails I just create a new instance and attach the disk to this machine? Or what is the stuff that I would need to do? Thanks

Comment: I was reading about azure recovery site and disaster recovery for VM. Is this not an option maybe?

Comment: that would take more time to recover and only works cross region, if you want cold backup vm you need to use azure backup

Comment: Cold backup with azure assured me zero data loss? Or I could have data loss becuase of the backup frecuency?

Comment: this is a completely different question, you should raise a new one (and probably accept\upvote this one), your initial one is answered. answer vm with premium disks - an easy way to obtain an SLA, without that - av set and 2 vms is the way to get an SLA.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I create the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406351/azure-vm-cold-backup-with-premium-disk