# Azure VM cold backup with Premium Disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

In case I have 2 VM with premium disk how can I make one to be a cold back. The VM will have SQL server using Premium disks and in case of a failure of one VM I need the other VM to have the last data inserted into SQL server.

How can this be done with Cold backup with Azure and assured me zero data loss?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to do this with **zero** RPO. Both Azure Backup and Azure Site recovery do not offer such RPO. you might be able to use some third party solution, but I dont think platform supports for a scenario you are asking.

Comment: But when having Premium disk, the data log and data files will be there so I guess same disk can be attached to a new VM. I dont require a zero downtime thing. If pulling a new VM and attach the same disk as fail VM takes 20 min thats fine. Is this possible?

Comment: yeah, that should work if the issue is with the VM itself but the data is fine

Comment: Exactly because every insert will happen into the SQL server data file that lives in the premium disk. The only doubt that I have is if I can attach the disk to a new VM created that is on a different region. Becuase what if the whole region is down and my disks lives there and I will need to launch a new VM in a different region and use same disks.